# I Have a With-Statement That Defines Two Values, and It Is Giving Me a Value Error. Why, and How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, with-statement, valueerror

This line of code is giving me

> ValueError: unsupported format character 't' (0x74) at index 7

```
with open("inventory.%s.txt" % file_number, "w") as f, open("gold.%.txt" % file_number, "w") as g:
```

What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: why is it all in one line?

Comment: Because that is most efficient and effective, and having it nested gives me an error.

Comment: you're missing an `%s` in your second line. Also white spaces are important for the reader and are Pythonic

Comment: What is white space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's trying to interpret the format string wrong - specifically, `"%s.t"`. You can truncate numbers with similar syntax, which might be confusing the formatter.

I recommend instead using either f-strings, if you're using python 3:

```
with open(f"inventory.{file_number}.txt", "w") as f, open(f"gold.{file_number}.txt", "w") as g:
```

or just the `str.format()` method otherwise:

```
with open("inventory.{}.txt".format(file_number), "w") as f, open("gold.{}.txt".format(file_number) as g:
```

which removes the ambiguity.